# Is there a clean linear algebra matrix or scalar form for this?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus

So let's say I have the following matrix equation to produce image $I$:
$$ I = W\cdot U \cdot Reshape(V \cdot S)\\
I \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times 1}\\
W \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times 2n}\\
U \in \mathbb{R}^{2n \times kn}\\
V \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times 50}\\
S \in \mathbb{R}^{50 \times n}\\$$

$Reshape()$ is an operation that vectorizes from $(k\times n)$ to $(kn \times 1)$. The worst part is that $U$ is actually an $n\times n$ diagonal block matrix where the blocks of size $2\times k$ are found along the diagonal and everywhere else is zero...

This is a linear regression problem (need to alternatively update $W,U,V$) I need to code for and am having trouble coming up with either a clean matrix solution form or scalar summation solution form for $W, U, V$ each. Oh and there are $m$ training images $I$ and $m$ "input" vectors $S$. Is this simply not tractable (is the only way to do this via a linear neural network)?

Edit: Reshape() operator is just same as the column-stacking vectorization operator

Comment: Is your reshape operation the same as the [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) operator described here?

Comment: Are the blocks of $U$ identical?

Comment: Yes it is the same as vectorization. No, the blocks of U are NOT identical and this part is killing me... Because V is same fo reach $n$ while U-blocks are Not...

Comment: There are two types of vectorization: one stacks rows, and one stacks columns.  Is your reshape the same as "column-stacking", which is the type of vectorization described on the page?

Comment: Oh, I believe it is column-stacking. So the first column of $VS$ which is length $k$ forms the first $k$ entries of vectorized $VS$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Is this linear regression task hopeless in closed form?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by linear regression in this context so I couldn't tell you.  I was going to type an answer about presenting the equation more cleanly, which might help you do those things

Comment: Any help is greatly appreciated. But basically I'm trying to find closed form expressions for W, U, V respectively in relation to the other matrices..

Comment: I mostly had this in mid: let $U_i$ denote the $i$th diagonal block of $U$.  We can write 
$$
U = \sum_{j=1}^n E_{jj} \otimes U_j
$$
where $E_{jj}$ denotes the $n\times n$ matrix with a $1$ in the $j,j$ entry and zeros elsewhere, and $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product.  With that, we have
$$
I = \sum_{j=1}^n W(E_{jj} \otimes U_j) \operatorname{vec}(VS)\\
= \sum_{j=1}^n W\operatorname{vec}(U_jVSE_{jj})
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I can definitely now see how I can find W give I, V, S, and U.

How would one find expression for V or Uj given the other variables? Do I have to find each Uj individually?

Comment: I don't see a way to avoid solving for the $U_j$ separately.  Also, you can get rid of the reshape operator and write the equation as 
$$
I = \sum_{j=1}^n W(e_j \otimes (U_jVSe_j))
$$
where $e_j$ is the $j$th column of the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: I see something that might work if we break up $W$.

Comment: That does make sense. And my last question would be: how can I take into account now that I have m images and m S matrices. All the above was for one image and one input matrix S

Comment: Now that the reshape operator is gone I think we can get an equation for the matrix whose columns are the successive images $I$.

Comment: Ah I see. So $I$ would be shape (p x m) and $S$ would be shape (50 x nm)? Or maybe rather $Se_j$ becomes shape (50 x m)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that last bit: $Se_j$ should have only one column.  For now I'll say that $I$ has shape $p\times m$ and we have several input matrices $S_1,S_2,\dots$ of the same shape as $S$ corresponding to the different inputs.

Comment: if $\mathcal I_q$ denotes the image resulting from input $S_q$, then we have
$$
\mathcal I_q = \sum_{j=1}^n W(e_j \otimes (U_jVS_qe_j)).
$$
If $\mathcal I$ denotes the matrix whose $q$th column is $\mathcal I_q$, then we have
$$
\mathcal I = 
\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{q = 1}^m [W(e_j^{(n)} \otimes (U_jVS_qe_j))]\cdot [e_q^{(m)}]^T
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use $\mathcal I$ for the image vector, and reserve $I$ for identity matrices.  Per the discussion in the comments, we have
$$
\mathcal I = \sum_{j=1}^n W(e_j \otimes (U_jVSe_j)).
$$
If we break $W$ up into $W = \sum_{q=1}^n e_q^T \otimes W_q$, i.e. if we take $W_1,\dots,W_n$ to be the block columns of $W$, then we have
$$
\mathcal I = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{q=1}^n (e_q^T \otimes W_q)(e_j \otimes (U_jVSe_j))  = \sum_{j=1}^n (W_jU_jVSe_j).
$$
We can now solve this equation for any particular $U_q$ by considering the equation
$$
W_qU_qVSe_q = \mathcal I  - \sum_{j\neq q} (W_jU_jVSe_j).
$$ 
We can solve for $V$ by writing the equation as 
$$
\mathcal I = \left(\sum_{j = 1}^n (Se_j)^T \otimes (W_j U_j)\right) \operatorname{vec}(V).
$$

---

Recap/derivation of information conveyed in comments on the question:

Let $U_i$ denote the $i$th diagonal block of $U$.  We can write 
$$
U = \sum_{j=1}^n E_{jj} \otimes U_j
$$
where $E_{jj}$ denotes the $n\times n$ matrix with a $1$ in the $j,j$ entry and zeros elsewhere, and $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product.  With that, we have
$$
I = \sum_{j=1}^n W(E_{jj} \otimes U_j) \operatorname{vec}(VS)\\
= \sum_{j=1}^n W\operatorname{vec}(U_jVSE_{jj})\\
= \sum_{j=1}^n W\operatorname{vec}(U_jVSe_je_j^T)\\
= \sum_{j=1}^n W(e_j \otimes (U_jVSe_j))
$$

If $\mathcal I$ denotes the matrix whose $q$th column is $\mathcal I_q$, then we have
$$
\mathcal I = 
\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{q = 1}^m [W(e_j^{(n)} \otimes (U_jVS_qe_j))]\cdot [e_q^{(m)}]^T
$$

Comment: This answer is a mess for now and might stay a mess for a while, but this way we can have everything in the same workspace.

Comment: In the last line of the first part of your post (right above the gray horizontal line) the second summation symbol should be from 1 to m right? not 1 to n? and this last line describes for all m images and m inputs

Comment: @NapoleonBonaparte no; I've scrapped the wider matrix $\mathcal I$ for now.  The $\mathcal I$ above the grey line refers to your column matrix.  Now that everything is written out however, I think it should be straighforward to generalize this to get expressions with $\mathcal I$ as a matrix with $m$ columns instead.

Comment: Ok yes I see the edits you've made. Thank you so much for all this help. This is absolutely godly.

Comment: @NapoleonBonaparte That's quite the compliment.  Glad to help! I'm disappointed that $U$ and $W$ had to stay broken up into $n$ pieces, but the end result is definitely neat.